# Annotation RequiredAttribute

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have something like this (use EF6, winform):

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage="{0} is required.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

But, at runtime, when user leaves this field blank, the system notices: "First Name is required. Do you want to correct the value ?".
How it does not have to words "Do you want to correct the value ?"
How to what to be replace it to be "First Name is required. Yes / No ?"

Comment: what? I'm sorry I do not understand the question at all...

Comment: Because your code somehow added that? Either in the ASP.NET form, Winforms window or whatever you used? The annotation doesn't really do anything. It's data for the *validation mechanism* that says what kind of validation to perform and what error message to generate if needed. It's the *application* that either displays a message or throws an exception

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. The message `First Name is required` is based on the values of the attributes `DisplayName` and `Required`

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the error message and tag your platform, is it ASP.NET MVC? Which version?

Comment: `Do you want to correct the value` is a message displayed by *DevExpress* controls.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem